# Simple python for playing Hangman

Tags: python

I'm learning python (started about 30 hours ago) and my son asked if I could make a hangman game.  Well, okay, I'll give that a try.  I'm sure this code is crap, but I'll never learn if I don't ask how I could have done this better.  Anything that's poor practice or doesn't scale?  (I won't ask what's sloppy - it's all sloppy.)

```
#
#  HANGMAN
#
# Import some things I think I'll need
import random  # For selecting from the word list randomly
import os  # Only use is to be able to clear the screen on Windows

# Create tiny word list to get started
word_list = ['sandwich', 'hamburger', 'pizza', 'nuggets',
             'fries', 'yogurt', 'popsicle']
# print(f"Selected words: {word_list}")  # Used to check my syntax for formatting from a list

# Build the parts of the hangman fellow
# Originally had just 4 parts, comments below are from expanding to 7 parts
hung_man1 = "                      O\n"
hung_man2 = "                     /"
hung_man3 = "|" #added this line and removed | from prior
hung_man4 = "\\ \n" #added this line and removed \\ \n from prior
hung_man5 = "                      |\n"
hung_man6 = "                     / "
hung_man7 = "\\ \n" # added this line and removed \\ \n from prior

# Used this to compare syntax of strings and lists
# print(f"Built hangman sequence: \n{hung_man1}{hung_man2}{hung_man3}{hung_man4}")

# Stuff the entire hangman construction into a list
hung_man = hung_man1,hung_man2,hung_man3,hung_man4, hung_man5, hung_man6, hung_man7

# Here it is, the whole reason for calling the OS - used one other time below
os.system('cls')

# An introduction screen.  Didn't try to make this nice.
print("")
print("")
print("   AND NOW IT'S TIME TO PLAY.... ")
print("          !!!HANGMAN!!!")
print("")
print("")

# Purpose is to check what it says it does - do I even need to comment this line?
# print(f"Created hangmand sequence list (should be the same): \n{hung_man}")

# Computer pics from a tiny list of words
computer_pick = random.choice(word_list)

# I store the length of the word
word_size = len(computer_pick)

# Initialize list used to display letter guessing status to player
display_word = []

# Used to check prior steps, could be killed now
# print(f"Computer selected {computer_pick} with length of {word_size}.")

# Quick function to chop the word into letters - currently unused.
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

# Hint should be unnecesary for the player since the letter placeholders are displayed
print("The word you are guessing has", word_size, "letters:")
print("")
print("")

# Initializing more variables game_round is not used, wrong_guess is counter, winner is status
game_round = 0
wrong_guess = 0
winner = False

# For each letter in the selected word, create list with placeholder string spaces
for character in range(word_size):
    display_word.append("___  ")

# Obviously used for debugging.  Probably not needed anymore
# print("Displayed word with placeholders for guesses has been built.")

# Exit conditions are winning or guessing wrong 7 times
while (wrong_guess < 7 and not winner):
    game_round += 1  # game_round is not used.

# First thing, display the word being guessed (will include correct guesses)
    for character in range(word_size):
        print(display_word[character], end="")
    print("")

# After displaying the word with guesses so far (initially zero), fetch another guess
    my_guess = input("What letter do you think is in the word? ")

# Execute the following only if the letter matches
    if my_guess.lower() in computer_pick:

# Create a list to index where the letters match (in case letter used more than once)
        matching_letters = [i for i, x in enumerate(computer_pick) if x == my_guess]

# Update the string list in display_word to reflect the correct guesses as capital letters
        for position in matching_letters:
            display_word[position] = f" {my_guess.upper()}   "

# If all of the blank spaces have been filled - show completed word and set win status
        if "___  " not in display_word:
            for character in range(word_size):
                print(display_word[character], end="")
            print("")
            winner = True

# If the guessed letter does not match, increment guesses and display hangman status
# This block also has the second use of the import OS to clear the screen
    else:
        wrong_guess += 1
        os.system('cls')
        print("")
        print("   Be Careful!  You're headed to the gallows!", end="")
        print("")

# As stated, this line prints the count (so I could check my logic)
        # print(wrong_guess)  # Keeps count of wrong guesses for debugging

# Prints as much of the hangman as suits the number of wrong guesses
        for hangman in range(wrong_guess):
            print(hung_man[hangman], end="")
        print("\n\n")

# What to do when the maximum number of wrong guesses have been reached
if wrong_guess > 6:
    print("                    OH NO\n            !! YOU'VE BEEN HUNG !!")

# What to do when the game has been won
else:
    print("")
    print("       !!YOU WON!!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Without rewriting the entire thing, there are a bunch of pointers I can give you:

```py
hung_man1 = "                      O\n"
hung_man2 = "                     /"
hung_man3 = "|" #added this line and removed | from prior
hung_man4 = "\\ \n" #added this line and removed \\ \n from prior
hung_man5 = "                      |\n"
hung_man6 = "                     / "
hung_man7 = "\\ \n" # added this line and removed \\ \n from prior
```

Is not something you would ever want to do.
When you find yourself naming variables `name` + `number`, think of lists:

```py
hung_man = [
    "                      O\n",
    "                     /",
    "|",  # added this line and removed | from prior
    "\\ \n",  # added this line and removed \\ \n from prior
    "                      |\n",
    "                     / ",
    "\\ \n",  # added this line and removed \\ \n from prior
]
```

This gets rid of

```py
# Stuff the entire hangman construction into a list
hung_man = hung_man1,hung_man2,hung_man3,hung_man4, hung_man5, hung_man6, hung_man7
```

which is incidentally not a list, but a `tuple`.
You may have never noticed because these behave the same in your code.

---

```py
os.system("cls")
```

does not work on Unix-based systems.

---

```py
print("")
print("")
print("   AND NOW IT'S TIME TO PLAY.... ")
print("          !!!HANGMAN!!!")
print("")
print("")
```

can just be

```py
print("\n\n   AND NOW IT'S TIME TO PLAY.... ")
print("          !!!HANGMAN!!!\n\n")
```

---

```py
# I store the length of the word
word_size = len(computer_pick)
```

If that comment helps you learn or remember in any way, keep it, but under normal circumstances, it should definitely be removed.
It just replicates what the code says almost verbatim.
If the code ever changes, the comment can become outdated and confusing (comments lie, code never does).

---

```py
# Quick function to chop the word into letters - currently unused.
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]
```

already exists in the form of `list(word)`.
Other than that, there is `str.split` to split a string according to some delimiter, which is not what your function does but might be handy for the future.
Note that you can just iterate over a string naturally, no need to convert it to a list or similar.

---

```py
print("The word you are guessing has", word_size, "letters:")
print("")
print("")
```

This could be

```py
print(f"The word you are guessing has {word_size} letters:", end="\n\n")
```

f-strings are powerful, convenient and fast.

---

```py
# Initializing more variables game_round is not used, wrong_guess is counter, winner is status
game_round = 0
wrong_guess = 0
winner = False
```

But `game_round` occurs later on, where it also has a similar comment.
It therefore seems used at first sight.
According to the comment, it is not.
Therefore, just use fewer comments in general and do not leave unused lines in the code, if at all possible.
Look into version control systems like `git` if you want to handle this properly.

`winner` sounds like it should be a string containing the winner's name or similar.
`won` is more suitable to signal a `bool`.

---

```py
for character in range(word_size):
    display_word.append("___  ")
```

works, but `display_word` is initialized to an empty list way earlier.
Keep the `display_word = []` line close to where it is used.

Also, `"___  "` works, but "explicit is better than implicit" (`import this`).
Someone might come along and think the spaces are accidents.

Lastly, list comprehension will make all of this faster and more readable:

```py
display_word = ["_" * 3 + " " * 2 for _ in range(word_size)]
```

Notice the `_` for "this variable is unused".
Your `character` variable from before was wrong or at least very misleading, since `range` yields integers.

---

```py
    for character in range(word_size):
        print(display_word[character], end="")
```

can just be

```py
    for word in display_word:
        print(word, end="")
```

---

```py
if my_guess.lower() in computer_pick:
```

is very confusing.
I entered capital letters into the game and they are silently dropped without error or hangman-penalty.

This is because the following line lacks a `.lower()` call to `my_guess`:

```py
        matching_letters = [i for i, x in enumerate(computer_pick) if x == my_guess]
```

Just put it into the `input` line:

```py
    my_guess = input("What letter do you think is in the word? ").lower()
```

Note that the list comprehension has poor variable naming as well, namely `x`.

---

```py
        if "___  " not in display_word:
            for character in range(word_size):
                print(display_word[character], end="")
            print("")
            winner = True
```

Here, `winner = True` can be replaced by a simple `break`.
This allows you to get rid of the `winner` variable altogether.

There is also the possibility to add an `else` block to your `while` block.
This executes if no `break` occurred but the `while` condition evaluated to `False`.
Aka, your `while` loop finished, no `break` was found (here, this is the winning flag).
Thus, you can put handling the losing situation there.

---

```py
if wrong_guess > 6:
```

Alongside `while wrong_guess < 7` above, you hard-coded the numbers here as well.
These two can go out of sync, breaking your program.
Using the `while`/`else` construct, you can avoid this problem altogether.

In general, extract any repetition into variables.
This also applies to for example `"___  "`, which you use multiple times.

Comment: Very helpful, and thanks for all the examples!  You spent a good amount of time on that explanaiton and it is really appreciated. I think I suspected that some of the things could "be done better", but actually making that happen wasn't happening. 
So again, kudos on examples. I'll definitely try to take advantage of this going forward.